# How do I eager load multiple foreign key rows from the same table, in Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a database table `Template` which stores user id's for `created_by`, `updated_by` and `deleted_by`. All three references the table `User`. I am trying to eager load all three users as full objects into the template objects, but I simply can't figure out how. All `include` documentation I find, refers only to model name alone, when defining a eager loading relationship. But in this case, that returns just one single user, and the attribute in each template object is named `User` instead of either of the three expected `createdBy`, `updatedBy` and `deletedBy`.

I have tried to figure out a way to include by column name or other reference. I have also tried to include all, but again, one User attribute, and three other integer keys appear as values.

```
    getTemplateList = async (req, res, t) => {
        const templateList = await Template.findAll({
            transaction: t,
            include: { all: true }
        });       
        return {status: 201, content: templateList};
    }
```

Relevant relation Definitions in Template:

```
    this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                as: 'createdBy',
                field: 'created_by',
                allowNull: false
            },
        });
        this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                as: 'updatedBy',
                field: 'updated_by',
                allowNull: false
            },
        });
        this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                as: 'deletedBy',
                field: 'deleted_by',
                allowNull: true
            },
        });
```

Relevant relation definitions in User:

```
 this.hasMany(Template, {
        foreignKey: {
            as: 'createdBy',
            field: 'created_by',
            allowNull: false
        },
    });
    this.hasMany(Template, {
        foreignKey: {
            as: 'updatedBy',
            field: 'updated_by',
            allowNull: false
        },
    });
    this.hasMany(Template, {
        foreignKey: {
            as: 'deletedBy',
            field: 'deleted_by',
            allowNull: true
        },
    });
```

I have tried both with and without the `as` attributes

Comment: Show model definitions and associations

Comment: @Anatoly done..

Comment: You definitely need to use aliases to distinguish associated objects from each other. As I remember you should indicate `name` prop as a field that used to link associated model and not `field`

Comment: changing field to name made no difference. field is used project wide from before, I am unfortunately still a bit new to node, and sequelize.

Comment: Please add model definitions

Comment: May I ask why that is important? I want to keep it as simple and specific as possible.

Comment: I wish to look at definitions of all fields involved in assciations

Comment: I have anonymized the fields and class names already, to be as simple as possible. I am not sure I can just copy paste the entire classes, due to confidentiality, and they are also quite complex and long. I didn't expect other parts of the code to be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated aliases in associations inside `foreignKey` option instead of indicating them next to `foreignKey` option:

```
this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                field: 'created_by',
                allowNull: false
            },
            as: 'createdBy',
        });
        this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                field: 'updated_by',
                allowNull: false
            },
            as: 'updatedBy',
        });
        this.belongsTo(User, {
            foreignKey: {
                field: 'deleted_by',
                allowNull: true
            },
            as: 'deletedBy',
        });
```

The same is for `User` associations.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really wanted to do this the correct way, and you helped me do just that! Now it works!